# Need group by counter as column returned

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

```
declare @tbl as table (
  Name nvarchar(10), Property int
)
```

Sample data in the table is like:

```
Name | Property
'A'  | 0
'A'  | 1
'A'  | 2
'A'  | 3
'B'  | 0
'B'  | 2
'B'  | 1
'C'  | 0
```

How can I return this table along with a column, that depicts the grouped column index?

Expected result:

```
Name | Property | Index
'A'  | 0        | 1
'A'  | 1        | 1
'A'  | 2        | 1
'A'  | 3        | 1
'B'  | 0        | 2
'B'  | 2        | 2
'B'  | 1        | 2
'C'  | 0        | 3
```

Please suggest! Thanks!

**Update**:

I used `dense_rank()` (in wrong fashion, I think) like this

```
SELECT 
   *, 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Property]) AS R
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DENSE_RANK:

```
select *
  , [Index] = dense_rank() over (order by Name)
from tbl
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32df2/3).

Comment: I tried the dense_rank() without proper understanding. No wonder I got wrong results. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Looks like you were practically there; just didn't need `partition by` for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

try like this...

```
Select Name,Property ,Dense_Rank() OVER 
    (ORDER BY Name) AS [Index] from TableName
```